# Cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" at the cluster scope

Tags: kubernetes, aws-application-load-balancer

Can't figure this out. I have the following setup:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  labels:
    app: alb-ingress-controller
  name: alb-ingress-controller
  namespace: kube-system
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  labels:
    app: alb-ingress-controller
  name: alb-ingress-controller
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
      - extensions
    resources:
      - configmaps
      - endpoints
      - events
      - ingresses
      - ingresses/status
      - services
    verbs:
      - create
      - get
      - list
      - update
      - watch
      - patch
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
      - extensions
    resources:
      - nodes
      - pods
      - secrets
      - services
      - namespaces
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: alb-ingress-controller
  name: alb-ingress-controller
  # Namespace the ALB Ingress Controller should run in. Does not impact which
  # namespaces it's able to resolve ingress resource for. For limiting ingress
  # namespace scope, see --watch-namespace.
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: alb-ingress-controller
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: alb-ingress-controller
    spec:
      containers:
        - args:
            # Limit the namespace where this ALB Ingress Controller deployment will
            # resolve ingress resources. If left commented, all namespaces are used.
            # - --watch-namespace=your-k8s-namespace

            # Setting the ingress-class flag below ensures that only ingress resources with the
            # annotation kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "alb" are respected by the controller. You may
            # choose any class you'd like for this controller to respect.
            - --ingress-class=alb

            # Name of your cluster. Used when naming resources created
            # by the ALB Ingress Controller, providing distinction between
            # clusters.
            - --cluster-name=kubernetes.someclustername.com

            # AWS VPC ID this ingress controller will use to create AWS resources.
            # If unspecified, it will be discovered from ec2metadata.
            - --aws-vpc-id=vpc-somevpc

            # AWS region this ingress controller will operate in. 
            # If unspecified, it will be discovered from ec2metadata.
            # List of regions: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#vpc_region
            - --aws-region=us-east-1

            # Enables logging on all outbound requests sent to the AWS API.
            # If logging is desired, set to true.
            # - ---aws-api-debug
            # Maximum number of times to retry the aws calls.
            # defaults to 10.
            # - --aws-max-retries=10
          env:
            # AWS key id for authenticating with the AWS API.
            # This is only here for examples. It's recommended you instead use
            # a project like kube2iam for granting access.
            # - name: ${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
            #  value: ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
            - name: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
              value:  redacted
            # AWS key secret for authenticating with the AWS API.
            # This is only here for examples. It's recommended you instead use
            # a project like kube2iam for granting access.
            - name: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
              value:  redacted
          # Repository location of the ALB Ingress Controller.
          #
          #image: docker.io/amazon/aws-alb-ingress-controller:v1.1.0
          #https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/releases/
          #image: public.ecr.aws/eks/aws-load-balancer-controller:v2.5.3
          #
          image: docker.io/amazon/aws-alb-ingress-controller:v2.4.5
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: server
          resources: {}
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      serviceAccountName: alb-ingress-controller
      serviceAccount: alb-ingress-controller
```

Log of alb shows:
pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.21.4/tools/cache/reflector.go:167: Failed to watch *v1.Pod: failed to list *v1.Pod: pods is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:alb-ingress-controller" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" at the cluster scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `ClusterRoleBinding` to assign the `ClusterRole` to the `ServiceAccount`.

```yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
# This cluster role binding allows anyone in the "manager" group to read secrets in any namespace.
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: alb-ingress-controller
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: alb-ingress-controller # Name is case sensitive
  namespace: kube-system
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: alb-ingress-controller
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#rolebinding-and-clusterrolebinding